# Cleaning inner self-intersections

Tags: mesh

I'm making a model of curved tube which have some self-intersections and wondering how to clean inner mesh in this area.
*Inersect(Knife)* tool with *Self Intersect* Source highlights the outer vertexes but they are non-closed so still need some work.
Maybe there is some semi-automatic way to clean it and leave only the outer shell? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't cut clean is because this kind of curved tube has self-reverting faces in the corners :

[image: self-reverting face]

You can fix it by using the knife, adding vertices and merging the closest vertices in those areas until you get this kind of result :

[image]

Then you should be able to select the self-intersected part of the tube with Ctrl+L :

[image: tube self-intersection]

I don't think there's any automated way to do this.